# Appending a string to a file with variable content

Tags: shell, variable, output

So I am using getent to reverse lookup a domain name to an IP. I need this IP in the munin-node config. I have the following code, but it just prints the IP and doesn't append to the config file.

```
HOSTIP= getent hosts google.nl | awk '{print $1}'
echo "allow ^$HOSTIP" >> /etc/munin/munin-node.conf
```

Comment: Write permissions issue probably. Also make sure that there is no spaces around `=`. If you remove the `>>` part, do you get expected output on screen?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou If I remove the spaces around = I'm getting an error 'hosts: not found'.. Is it even possible to assign the output of an function to a variable like this?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Removing the >> prints out the IP and allow ^'' underneath eachother.

Comment: The correct command to store the ouput of getent to a variable is hostip=$(getent hosts google.nl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is wrong

```
HOSTIP= getent
```

The space between "=" and "getent" dont work in bash.

And you need to put command inside a sub-shell "$()"

```
HOSTIP=$(getent hosts google.nl | awk '{print $1}')

echo $HOSTIP
2800:3f0:4001:801::2003
```